# Допустимо ли словосочетание "забрать кого/что ОТ кого-то"?

Tags: управление, глаголы, предлоги

Можно ли сказать: "Забрать ребенка от родителей", или допустимо только "забрать у родителей"? Речь — о действиях органов опеки.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Доступные мне словари не дают ответа на этот вопрос. Приходится положиться на примеры из Нацкорпуса и свою интуицию. Вывод таков. Применительно к органам опеки, "забрать ребенка **у** родителей" значит то же, что "отнять ребенка у родителей". Так можно сказать, например, в случае лишения родительских прав. "Забрать ребенка **от** родителей" (опять же, применительно к данной ситуации) означает отдалить его физически, лишить контакта с родителями.
Ср. Органы опеки забрали ребенка **у** родителей и лишили их родительских прав. <---> Органы опеки забрали ребенка **от** родителей и поместили его в интернат. (Примеры мои)

Answer (score 0):

А почему недопустимо-то? В словаре я такое значение "от" не нашёл, но есть же устойчивое выражение: "От греха подальше". По своей функции в предложении оно играет ту же роль, что и "от родителей" в Вашем примере. То есть забрать, чтобы обезопасить от какого-то неблагоприятного фактора. Тут иной оттенок фразы, нежели при употреблении "у". Думаю, тут уместно провести параллель со значением "обозначение исходной точки передвижения предмета или информации", например: "Увести от опасности", "Забрать от родителей". Был там, а теперь уже не там. То есть, когда мы употребляем "у", акцент на том, что забрали именно у родителей, а когда используем "от", основной смысл уже в том, что самое главное, что ребёнок уже не там.

Comment: Уважаемый Третий глаз, извините, что так поздно отвечаю вам. Вы наверное, не заметили, что мы говорим о разном: я описывала значение предлога "У" с существительными, а вы говорите о приставке "У" при глаголах движения. Не буду повторяться, советую ещё раз прочитать выше. Спасибо. Всего наилучшего.

Comment: "От греха подальше" отвечает на вопрос куда? Аналогом может быть "от родителей подальше", но это не наш случай.

Answer (score 0):

Предлог "у" имеет сильное закулисное значение принадлежности, власти обладателя над объектом. Говорим же мы "у меня есть что-то" то есть "я владею этим", или же я говорю "у меня болит голова" и не могу сказать: "моя голова болит", потому что "голова" как бы находится в моём подчинении, потому что она есть неделимая часть меня и я главный владелец головы. Вот ещё пример: в русском языке имеется присущая европейским языкам (не всем) структура типа: "мой сын занимается спортом", но по-русски мы можем также сказать: "у меня сын занимается спортом". Так можно сказать именно потому, что предлог "у" обладает силой выражать скрытое представление о связанности обладаемого и обладателя, о причастности их друг к другу или через родство по крови, или через сближение, к примеру, по соседству (ср.: У меня сосед...) и пр. Отсюда можно выйти на анализируемые фразы. Вариант "отобрать ребёнка У родителей" по логике должен означать нарушение этой природной связанности по крови, то есть лишить родителей родительских прав. "Отобрать ребёнка от родителей" означает отобрать ребёнка у тех, оттуда, где ребёнок временно находился. Временно здесь может означать и незаконно. К примеру, отобрать детей от родителей, которые уже лишены родительских прав и каким-то образом удерживают детей у себя. Или отобрать детей от отца, лишённого родительских прав, который пытался незаконно увезти детей в другую страну. Таков расклад этих предлогов, но в жизни многие не учитывают этих тонкостей и в своей речи подменяют одно другим.